# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt5

I just installed PyQt 5.7.0 on my google compute engine machine which running on a ubuntu 16.04:

[image]

However, when I wanted to run PyQt and import some module, it produce Segmentation fault (core dumped) error as shown:

[image]

Can I know how do I solve it? I have been searching an answer for this for hours and still can't find an answer. Will be greatly appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: Did you compile `PyQt5` yourself? Have you tried with a different `Python` version? I had the same problem you described and I managed to solve it by downgrading Python down to version `3.4.3`.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I did try python 5.6.2, and it works but it doesnt support QtWebEngine, it uses QtWebKit Instead

Comment: Python 5.6.2??????? I guess you meant `PyQt 5.6.2`, you need to downgrade `Python`, not `PyQt` ;)

Comment: @DanielePantaleone opps sorry i was using python 3.4.3 and PyQt5.6.2, I was using pip3, Did you use the latest ver of pyqt?'

Comment: I used `Python 3.4.3` + `PyQt 5.7` and `SIP 4.18.1`. I compiled everything myself on top of `Qt5.7` and everything went just fine.

Comment: ok thanks bro, I will try that out :)

Comment: can I know your ubuntu ver?

Comment: I don't use `Ubuntu` but `CentOS`, but it's the same ;)

Comment: Can you please get a stacktrace by installing `gdb`, running `gdb $(which python3)`, then in the gdb shell do `r`, make it segfault, and do `bt`?

Answer (score 4):

You can try (as explained in the comments) to compile `PyQt5.7` yourself, using a different version of Python (`3.4.3` and `3.4.4` worked for me, everything above `3.5` did not). Note that I also compiled `Qt5.7` myself, but you can use the one provided by the installer. Here is a short, hopefully exhaustive, set of commands to setup a virtual environment:

Install dependencies using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxrender-dev libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libssl-dev libcups2-dev python3-pip git
```

Install Python 3.4.4:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/Python-3.4.4.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.4.4.tar.xz
cd Python-3.4.4
./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

Create the virtual environment:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.4 ~/python34
source ~/python34/bin/activate
```

Install Qt:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd ~/Downloads/qt5
git checkout 5.7
./init-repository
./configure -prefix ~/Qt/5.7/gcc_64 -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -release -confirm-license
make -j 5
make install
```

Install SIP:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pyqt/sip/sip-4.18.1/sip-4.18.1.tar.gz
tar xf sip-4.18.1.tar.gz
cd sip-4.18.1
python configure.py
make
sudo make install
```

Install PyQt:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pyqt/PyQt5/PyQt-5.7/PyQt5_gpl-5.7.tar.gz
tar xf PyQt5_gpl-5.7.tar.gz
cd PyQt5_gpl-5.7
python configure.py --qmake ~/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake --disable QtPositioning --no-qsci-api --no-designer-plugin --no-qml-plugin --confirm-license
make -j 5
sudo make install
```

Comment: I had a segmentation fault core dumped error appearing only on exiting the PyQt app. Installing the dev dependencies (clearing out some unmet dependencies of libpng-dev via [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/solvespace/solvespace/issues/370#issuecomment-448085420)) worked for me well. I installed PyQt5 via `sudo apt-get Python3-PyQt5`. I'm on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Caveats:

- I'm going to assume that you can't run any GUI programs right now in your vm.
- I'm not that familiar with GCE platform and have not tried what I'm going to propose

Follow the steps at [Your desktop on Google Cloud Platform](https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5) to install a desktop GUI manager in the GCE vm  (it will be X11-based for Linux OS), as well as vnc server.

Once you are vnc'd in to your vm using realvnc or tightvnc viewer, a GUI app will likely run. You may have to change the X11 DISPLAY variable -- eventhough the above link does not discuss this -- because AFAIR *nix systems use a separate desktop session for VNC than the one currently logged in.

I doubt it will run if there is no user logged on to the GCE vm.

Comment: This can't be the issue, QtCore doesn't contain anything needing a display.

Comment: @thecompiler you're  right but if all else fails it could be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

If you installed PyQt5 with apt or apt-get, now do also

> sudo pip3 install pyqt5

Answer (score -1):

You cannot run a GUI program (PyQt) remotely, unless both machines use X11 protocol with properly set `DISPLAY` variables and `xhost` permissions. I doubt that Google compute engine is configurable to run in the X11 mode.

Comment: Then is it possible to run PyQt on GCE? because I needed it for my web automation(ie: Form submission with cookie and js enabled because cookie are set using js)

Comment: @dramasea As I said, you cannot do it. For any practical purpose, "you cannot" means "impossible."

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, since he's getting the segmentation fault while importing `PyQt5` modules, not when running a program. I can successfully import `PyQt5`modules on a `CentOS` machine w/o X11. To me it looks there have been some compilation problems.

Comment: Indeed: `from PyQt5 import *` is a complete no-op and `QtCore` doesn't contain any gui-related stuff.

Answer (score -3):

When you import PyQt5, it will also import PyQt5.QtCore because PyQt5.QtCore is part of PyQt5.